# Spawn a program within a Pseudo Console via cmd and/or powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, command-prompt

I want to spawn a program (lets say `python.exe`) from either `CMD.exe` or `powershell.exe` when they are not invoked from the desktop, but from another program, something like `myprogram.exe -> cmd.exe (so in this stage cmd has not allocated a Console) -> python.exe`. I need this to allow me to pass all of my input (even `Ctrl-C`) to the target spawned program.

On linux, this can be achieved by either:

- `script -qefc 'python' /dev/null`
- `python -c "import pty; pty.spawn('python')"`

I've found [CreatePseudoConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/createpseudoconsole) function (which can be invoked via `powershell`), but I don't know how to pipe the current STDIN/STDOUT to that Pseudo Console.